# Background loop video not working on mobile phone

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

```
<video  autoplay muted loop id="videobg">
    <source src="bgvideo/bgvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Hey guys i am using a background video for a website it perfectly works on pc but on iphone it's not working
Link to website: https://fierce-atoll-94899.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely need to add the `playsinline` attribute as well, otherwise e.g. on iPhone the Video would only be played in full screen.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: one more  problem on iphone when i scroll down in the website the video creates a glitch.and video is not being played in loop as well.